# Parse CSV with far future dates to Parquet

Tags: pandas, csv, date, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I’m trying to read a CSV into Pandas, and then write it to Parquet. The challenge is that the CSV has a date column with a value of 3000-12-31, and apparently Pandas has no way to store that value as an actual date. Because of that, PyArrow fails to read the date value.

An example file and code to reproduce is

`test.csv`

```
t
3000-12-31
```

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=["t"])
schema = pa.schema([pa.field("t", pa.date64())])
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=schema)
```

This gives (a somewhat unhelpful error)

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You can't have that date represented as a datetime64; it's too large. The biggest date you can have is `pd.Timestamp.max` or `Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')`. So even though you specify it to parse the date, it tries and fails so it simply keeps the column as the string. Your only real option is to store it as a `Period`, `df['t'] = df['t].apply(pd.Period)`, but I don't know if pyarrow supports that dtype

Comment: Yeah, I did try that, and indeed PyArrow doesn't seem to accept `Period` as a date type. So I need some workaround I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas datetime columns (which use the `datetime64[ns]` data type) indeed cannot store such dates.

One possible workaround to convert the strings to `datetime.datetime` objects in an object dtype column. And then pyarrow should be able to accept them to create a date column.
This conversion could eg be done with `dateutil`:

```py
>>> import dateutil
>>> df['t'] = df['t'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
>>> df
                     t
0  3000-12-31 00:00:00

>>> table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=schema)
>>> table
pyarrow.Table
t: date64[ms]
```

or if you use a fixed format, using `datetime.date.strptime` is probably more reliable:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> df['t'] = df['t'].apply(lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d"))
>>> table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=schema)
>>> table
pyarrow.Table
t: date64[ms]
```

Comment: This works really well, thanks. I think the only issue now is that `parse` (or maybe `parse` in combination with `apply`) is pretty slow. I think that's something I'll just have to live with.

Comment: Yes, it is expected that this is slower than `pd.to_datetime`. An alternative might be to use numpy instead of pandas (`np.array(["2020-01-01"]).astype("datetime64[D]")` parses the strings as well). But then the conversion to a pyarrow table is a bit more complex/manual, as you can't use `from_pandas`.